# Irreducible polynomials over fields

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations, irreducible-polynomials

> Verify if the following polynomial over the indicated field is irreducible.
>
> $p=x^4+2x^2-x+1 \in \mathbb{Z_7}[x]$

Because $p$ is degree $4$, it can only be factorized as the following cases:

*i)* $p=h \cdot g$, where either $h$ or $g$ is degree $1$ and the other is $3$

*ii)* $p=h \cdot g$, where  $h$ and $g$ are degree $2$

For *i)* I can simply calculate the zeros of $p$ and check if there is any $h$ or $g$ with degree $1$.

We are in $\mathbb{Z_7}[x],$ so $x \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

$p(0)=1$

$p(1)=3$

$p(2)=2$

$p(3)=6$

$p(4)=5$

$p(5)=6$

$p(6)=5$

Because $p$ has no zeros, it can't be factorized like I said in *i)*. Now there is only the case *ii)* to verify.

For this I can suppose $p=x^4+2x^2-x+1=(ax^2+bx+c)(dx^2+ex+f)$

$\Leftrightarrow x^4+2x^2-x+1=(ad)x^4+(ae+bd)x^3+(af+be+cd)x^2+(bf+ce)x+cf $

$\begin{cases}
ad=1 \\
ae+bd=0 \\
af+be+cd=2 \\
bf+ce=-1=6 \\
cf=1 \
\end{cases}
\Leftrightarrow   \begin{cases}
ad=1 \\
ae=-bd \\
af+be+cd=2 \\
bf=6-ce \\
cf=1 \
\end{cases}$

Is there a simple way to solve this system of equations? I've start reading some stuff about irreducible polynomials and some times when I get to this part I get stuck in some systems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we checked that $p$ has no root in $\mathbb{F}_7$, we just have two possible configurations:

1. $p$ is the product of two quadratic (monic) irreducible factors.
    In such a case $\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{49}\times\mathbb{F}_{49} $;
2. $p$ is irreducible. In such a case $\mathbb{F}_7[x]/(p(x))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_{7^4}$.

In the former case, by raising some element of the ring to the $48$-th power we either get a polynomial which is not coprime with $p(x)$, or the element $1$. Let us reduce $x^{48}\pmod{p(x)}$ and $\pmod{7}$ in order to check that we are in the latter case.
$$ x^4 = -2x^2+x-1\tag{A} $$
$$ x^8 = 3x^3-3x^2+2x-3\tag{B} $$
$$ x^{12} = 2x^3+x^2+3x+1\tag{C} $$
$$ x^{24} = -x^3+x^2+3\tag{D} $$
$$ x^{48} = -x^3-2x^2+x+3.\tag{E} $$
$-x^3-2x^2+x+3$ is coprime with $p(x)$ and differs from $1$.
 It follows that $p(x)$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_7$. This is more or less what softwares do to prove or disprove the irreducibility of a polynomial over some finite field.

For the general case, have a look at the [Cantor-Zassenhaus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) and [Berlekamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm)'s algorithms.

A brute-force approach is to consider all the $\frac{7^2-7}{2}=21$ monic irreducible quadratic polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_7$ and check that they do not divide $p(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Since your original polynomial has leading coefficient 1, in any factorization you can always multiply each factor by a constant and assume that the leading coefficients of the factors are 1.  So you can assume that $a=d=1$. That should make the system easier to solve.

Comment: Can I do that whenever the leading coefficient is $1$? I tought I could only do that when I was working on $\mathbb{Z_2}$ because if $x \cdot y=1$ , then $x,y,$ can only be $1$ in  $\mathbb{Z_2}$

Comment: For example if $a=d=6$ , the condition $a \cdot d =1$ still is true. So I can't conclude $a=d=1$ like you said?

Comment: If $a = d = 6$, then multiply the first factor by 6 and divide the second factor by 6.  The product is unchanged while both factors now have leading coefficient 1.  If there is any factorization at all, then there is one in which the leading coefficients are 1, so (since you are trying to prove that there is no factorization) you can assume $a=d=1$.